# Why doesn't the text in my footer line up?

Tags: html, css, footer

Recently I have been making a footer for a website that me and my friends are making and the text isn't lined up. I wanted the copyright to be at the bottom and the links and contact information to be all next to each other, sort of like the footer of stackoverflow. The footer has not been working the way that I thought that it would be. I have tried many ways to change the where the text is but it doesn't seem to work. It should be a simple fix so if you have the time please take a look at the code. Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="contact">
            <h3> Contact Us: </h3>
            <p>ourEmail@ourSite.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popular">
            <h3> Popular Games: </h3>
            <p><a href="#">Happy Wheels</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Flappy Bird</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Impossible Quiz</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="footerNav">
            <h3>Pages</h3>              
            <p><a href="http://www.freeninjagaming.site50.net">Home</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Games</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">About Us</a></p>
        </div><br>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p> Copyright 2014 Dylan Maniatakes, Jacob Snarr and Mitchell Conrad </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <style>
        footer{
            clear: both;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-align: center;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }
        .contact {
            float: left;
        }
        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #c23b3b
        }
        a:hover{
            color: darkred;
        }
        .footerNav {
            float: right;
        }
        </style>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed `float` and used `display:inline-block` to the elements you wanted side-by-side.  I then added `display:block` to the copyright to make it its own line.  I also added an H3 tag for Navigation so that they would all line up nice with `vertical-align: top`.

[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/G78AT/)

**OUTPUT**

---

[image]

**HTML**

---

```
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="contact">
             <h3> Contact Us: </h3>

            <p>ourEmail@ourSite.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popular">
             <h3> Popular Games: </h3>

            <p><a href="#">Happy Wheels</a>

            </p>
            <p><a href="#">Flappy Bird</a>

            </p>
            <p><a href="#">Impossible Quiz</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="footerNav">
             <h3> Navigation: </h3>

            <p><a href="http://www.freeninjagaming.site50.net">Home</a>

            </p>
            <p><a href="#">Games</a>

            </p>
            <p><a href="#">About Us</a>

            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p>Copyright 2014 Dylan Maniatakes, Jacob Snarr and Mitchell Conrad</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**CSS**

---

```
 footer {
     clear: both;
     font-family: Arial;
     text-align: center;
     border-top: 1px solid black;
 }
 footer div {
     display: inline-block;
     vertical-align: top;
     margin-right: 20px;
 }
 footer div:last-child {
     margin-right: 0;
 }
 footer .copyright {
     display: block;
 }
 .contact {
 }
 a {
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #c23b3b
 }
 a:hover {
     color: darkred;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have some questionable styling choices, but that's okay! We're all here to learn. I have a [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Morklympious/whRmH/#base) that you might use as a starting point. I basically gave a style rule to give all divs inside of `footer` a property of `display: inline-block`, which will put them all in a line if there's room to accommodate them.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<footer>
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="contact">
            <h3> Contact Us: </h3>
            <p>ourEmail@ourSite.com</p>
        </div>
        <div class="popular">
            <h3> Popular Games: </h3>
            <p><a href="#">Happy Wheels</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Flappy Bird</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Impossible Quiz</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="footerNav">
            <h3>Pages</h3>              
            <p><a href="http://www.freeninjagaming.site50.net">Home</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">Games</a></p>
            <p><a href="#">About Us</a></p>
        </div><br>
        <div class="copyright">
            <p> Copyright 2014 Dylan Maniatakes, Jacob Snarr and Mitchell Conrad </p>
        </div>
        </div>
        <style>
        footer{
            clear: both;
            font-family: Arial;
            text-align: center;
            border-top: 1px solid black;
        }
        .contact, .popular, .footerNav {
            float: left;
        }

        .copyright {
          clear:both;
          float:left;
          }

        a {
            text-decoration: none;
            color: #c23b3b
        }
        a:hover{
            color: darkred;
        }

        .footer div {
           margin-left:10px;
          margin-right:10px;
          }
        </style>
</footer>
</html>
```